# Alfresco Document download url not working

Tags: alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have a fresh-installed Alfresco Community v6.1.1.
I need to be able to share a folder (and its files).

I understand no such feature is available stock from Alfresco Share, and thus, I downloaded and installed a folder-sharing extension I found on github. Seems to work fine, upto the moment I try to download a file located in a shared folder. I get a 404 error.

The url is http://192.168.2.158:8080/alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/029a75d7-fe85-448d-b71d-f53666f4e2ba/my%20text%20file

Actually, the 404 error is even triggered at this address **http://192.168.2.158:8080/alfresco/d** (or /alfresco/download)

The code that generates the download link looks ok, but I'm not expert :

```
<a href="${url.context}${child.url}" target="new">${child.properties.name}</a>
```

How come the /alfresco/download address does not work on my server ? Did I miss some configuration step ?

Thank you for any help you could provide.
Yann

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell which github Alfresco Extension you're using - so how should/could we help you?

The URL pattern `/alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore` is from the Alfresco download servlet which has been removed from Alfresco in version 5.x so you will not have any luck with this approach.

You say you "need to be able to share a folder (and its files)". You mean the receiver should be able to access this folder and files without having an Alfresco-User or what is exactly your use case?

There are at least two commercial extensions for creating shared folders and files to be accessed from external users I know of with similar functionality and which are supported for your Alfresco version:

- Loftux ShareBox for Alfresco
- ecm4u External Share for Alfresco (our own product)